# How can I provide a chat interface to search my structured database

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, chat, chatbot

I have an application that is used by medical professionals to search medical documents (structured). The documents have a variety of fields and can be searched, filtered and sorted in many different ways. The data can be transformed into CSV or other formats if required.

The current implementation is documents are stored in an ElasticSearch database. We then have a UI with inputs and filters to help users find what they are looking for. (SearchKit).

Because the data is complex and numerous ways to query this increases the complexity of the app. Many users are not technically literate so we need to strike a balance between usability and providing the options required. Different medical professionals also use different terms for the same thing making it increasingly difficult to manage.

With the increased popularity of chat interfaces I wondered if it would be possible to provide our users with the ability to query the database using natural language queries too.

I have done some research into this but unsure if it is possible with today's technology. I have explored tools such as AWS Lex but these appear to be more rigid in their applications. I've also read about NLP and NLQ.

This question is asking what advice or documentation I could look at to achieve this (if it is possible).

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are some Elastic docs about NPL. There is a lot of well-evolved stuff and I think it fits your need.
You can start here:

- [How to deploy natural language processing (NLP): Getting started](https://www.elastic.co/pt/blog/how-to-deploy-natural-language-processing-nlp-getting-started)
- [Natural language processing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/current/ml-nlp.html)